# Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem-proof

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, sampling-theory

I don't understand the last derivation.
Why there isn't $\pi$ in the sinc function?
I would think that it is a mistake , but even in the Wikipedia it appears without $\pi$.
[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [some conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function), the $\mathrm{sinc}$ function has a $\pi,$ in it, i.e. $$ \mathrm{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$
instead of $$\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$